# Extract OSM nodes: all surface parking spots in germany

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nodes

I would like to extract all surface parking spots in germany as nodes from osm. 
Gladly I have found overpass-turbo.eu, but unfortunately it is not working for my purpose... 
Either the server is too busy or I get a timeout.
My request is:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“parking=surface in germany”
*/
[out:xml][timeout:500000];
// fetch area “germany” to search in
{{geocodeArea:germany}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “parking=surface”
  node["parking"="surface"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what happens if you try a smaller area?

Comment: it is still not working for geocodeArea:bavaria or geocodeArea:cologne

Comment: Your timeout value is way too high, that's almost 6 days! In any case try a really small area first (e.g. Saarland) to check if results are what you're looking for. I doubt that's  the case with your current query.

Comment: Maybe you should look into osmfilter on a Geofabrik extract,

Comment: The bigger issue is that many amenity=parking are mapped as way, so for Germany, you're missing out on 327695 ways, see: https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=parking

Answer (score 4):

It worked with the following code

```
[timeout:600];
{{geocodeArea:germany}}->.searchArea;

// gather results
node[amenity="parking"](area.searchArea);

// print results
out body;
```